# En python, la comprension del diccionario con una clave principal que esta en una lista puede omitirse la linea del titulo?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo estos datos:

```
lista_casa = [['Nro','Casa','Jardin','Codigo','Habitaciones'],['020','si','Si',1,'4'],['310','si','Si',5,'6'],['52','no','no',3,'2']]
```

Estoy haciendo una funcion que me permita tomar **Codigo** como llave o clave (key):

```
def diccionarioDpt(dictDpt):
    result = {}
    for row in dictDpt:
        key = row[3] #Variable Codigo
        if key in result:
            pass
        result[key] = row[0:]
    return result

dico_data=diccionarioDpt(lista_casa)
print(dico_data)
```

La salida que obtengo por la funcion es esta:

`{'Codigo': ['Nro', 'Casa', 'Jardin', 'Codigo', 'Habitaciones'], 1: ['020', 'si', 'Si', 1, '4'], 5: ['310', 'si', 'Si', 5, '6'], 3: ['52', 'no', 'no', 3, '2']}`

Me gustaria poder omitir la linea de las variables, claro igual que mantenga **Codigo** como llave (key) y la salida que estoy buscando es la siguiente:

`{1: ['020', 'si', 'Si', 1, '4'], 5: ['310', 'si', 'Si', 5, '6'], 3: ['52', 'no', 'no', 3, '2']}`

Cuales son sus recomendaciones o consejos?

Comment: Quieres quitar los "[]"?

Comment: No, me gustaria quitar la linea de las variables, es decir la linea: `'Codigo': ['Nro', 'Casa', 'Jardin', 'Codigo', 'Habitaciones']` manteniendo la variable codigo como key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma algo más genérica asumiendo solo que la entrada es un iterable con objetos indizables de la misma longitud, en el que el primero son las cabeceras, es usar un iterador:

```
lista_casa = [['Nro','Casa','Jardin','Codigo','Habitaciones'],
              ['020','si','Si',1,'4'],
              ['310','si','Si',5,'6'],
              ['52','no','no',3,'2']]

def diccionarioDpt(dictDpt, key):
    data_iter = iter(dictDpt)
    header = next(data_iter)
    idx = header.index(key)
    return {row[idx]: row[:idx] + row[idx + 1: ] for row in data_iter}

dico_data = diccionarioDpt(lista_casa, key='Codigo')
print(dico_data)
```

> ```
> {1: ['020', 'si', 'Si', '4'],
>  5: ['310', 'si', 'Si', '6'],
>  3: ['52', 'no', 'no', '2']}
> ```

Si no deseas extraer la "columna" usada como clave, entonces simplemente:

```
def diccionarioDpt(dictDpt, key):
    data_iter = iter(dictDpt)
    header = next(data_iter)
    idx = header.index(key)
    return {row[idx]: row for row in data_iter}
```

> ```
> {1: ['020', 'si', 'Si', 1, '4'],
>  5: ['310', 'si', 'Si', 5, '6'],
>  3: ['52', 'no', 'no', 3, '2']}
> ```

Si quieres una copia superficial de cada sublista, en éste segundo caso puedes simplemente usar slicing también:  `row[idx]: row[:]`.

El usar un iterador evita generar una copia de la lista para excluir la primera sublista o usar un condicional en cada iteración para comprobar el índice. El propio `for` ya generaría un iterador implícitamente, solo nos limitamos a pasar ya un iterador en el que hemos consumido el primer elemento y el `for` simplemente iterará desde dónde lo dejamos.

El argumento `key` permite definir que columna se usará como clave, ésto hace la función más reutilizable, si quieres prescindir de él siempre puedes "hardcodear" el índice:

```
def diccionarioDpt(dictDpt):
    data_iter = iter(dictDpt)
    next(data_iter)
    return {row[3]: row for row in data_iter}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla ! Con el ejemplo funciona pero en la base de datos me presenta una inconsistencia creo que es debido a la iteracion de la cabecera.

Comment: Me gustaria que me recomendara que otra manera puedo hacerlo sin la iteracion @FJSevilla

Comment: ¿Sin el for?¿o sin el iterador? Sea como sea, implícita o explícitamente vas a tener que usar ambos a no ser que usaras un while pero sería una forma terriblemente ineficiente y ya no hablemos de legibilidad. Otra opción es usar programación funcional, pero de nuevo, más ineficiente y hay un ciclo interno igualmente. ¿Por qué quieres evitar el ciclo? ¿Por tu primer comentario? Si es así, ¿podrías agregar un [mcve] que muestre el problema e ilustre a que te refieres con "incosistencia"?

Comment: La formulacion de lo que queria lograr en el ejercicio es hacer un diccionario con la key en **Codigo** y por valores tomara lista de listas de los datos, he ahi el problema de mi inconsistencia @FJSevilla